# Two inner classes within a RecyclerView class to display different layouts

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am trying to declare two inner classes within a RecyclerView class using Kotlin. Currently, when I try this like below, I get an error message on both classes. What do I need to change to make this work on Kotlin?

```kotlin
    class ChatAdapter(private val dataSet: ArrayList<ChatMessage>, private val receiverProfilImage: Bitmap,val senderId:String) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {


     class SentMessageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
     {
         lateinit var binding: ItemContainerSentMessageBinding

         SentMessageViewHolder(itemContainerSentMessageBinding: ItemContainerSentMessageBinding)  {
             binding = itemContainerSentMessageBinding
         }

         fun setData(chatMessage: ChatMessage)
         {
             binding.textMessage.text = chatMessage.message
             binding.textDateTime.text = chatMessage.dateTime
         }
     }


     class ReceivedMessageViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
     {
         lateinit var binding: ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding

         ReceivedMessageViewHolder(itemContainerReceivedMessageBinding: ItemContainerReceivedMessageBinding) {
             binding = itemContainerReceivedMessageBinding
         }

         fun setData(chatMessage: ChatMessage,receiverProfilImage:Bitmap)
         {
             binding.textMessage.text = chatMessage.message
             binding.textDateTime.text = chatMessage.dateTime
             binding.imageProfil.setImageBitmap(receiverProfilImage)
         }

     ...
     }
```

> Expecting member declaration

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to declare secondary constructors of these classes using a syntax that is sort of like Java constructor syntax.

You don't need secondary constructors anyway, since the only way you want to instantiate one of these is by using a view binding. (So, you can look at the Kotlin documentation to learn how to write a secondary constructor. I won't explain it here since you don't need it in this case.)

There is no reason to use `lateinit` for a property that can be initialized during construction time. In this case, it can just be a property declared in your primary constructor. The root view of the binding is the base view of your ViewHolder, so you can pass `binding.root` to the superclass constructor.

```
 class SentMessageViewHolder(val binding: ItemContainerSentMessageBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
 {
     fun setData(chatMessage: ChatMessage)
     {
         binding.textMessage.text = chatMessage.message
         binding.textDateTime.text = chatMessage.dateTime
     }
 }
```